# XmlDocument don't save white spaces between tags

Tags: .net, xml, xmldocument

Part of XML:

```
<text:p>text1 <text:span>text2</text:span> <text:span>text3</text:span>text4</text:p>
```

You can see a space between text:span tags with text2 and text3. When I call XmlDocument.Load method I have this picture:

```
<text:p>text1 <text:span>text2</text:span><text:span>text3</text:span>text4</text:p>
```

White space was removed, but I need this space in this place.
Set  property "PreserveWhitespace = true" don't help

Comment: Why do you need white space between tags aside from readability?

Comment: What do you mean by "When I call XmlDocument.Load method I have this picture"? Calling `XmlDocument.Load` loads the xml from the source into the `XmlDocument` class so that you can use the `XmlDocument` api to manipulate it. How are you turning the `XmlDocument` back into a string to post it above?

Comment: I can see a load result in XmlDocument.InnerText. And I see that white space is absent between tags.

Comment: Matt Ball, because text in text:p and text:span tags it's parts of one string (text:span set diferent styles for some parts of this string), and I need to get this string after load. This white space it's just space between two words.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PreserveWhitespace works for me. My sample code is

```
    string xml = "<root><p>text1 <span>text2</span> <span>text3</span>text4</p></root>";
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
    doc.LoadXml(xml);

    Console.Write(doc.InnerXml);
```

This prints

```
<root><p>text1 <span>text2</span> <span>text3</span>text4</p></root>
```

with the space between the span elements still there.

Answer (score 1):

For those using XDocument instead of XmlDocument:

```
XDocument.Load(xml, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace)
```